# Profiling in microseconds precision in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, performance, time

I am on Win 10 OS, python 2.7.

Both time.time() and datetime.datetime.now() module give me millisecond precision and I would like to have in microseconds precision.

I have a python application keep running, it has its busiest time (big data flow in an out) and thus the time spent on each function would be vary. I would like to profile each function and let the application keep running, aim to identify the bottleneck of the function, where microseconds is needed in this case.

```
import datetime
print datetime.datetime.now()
2018-07-05 16:29:39.185000

import time
print time.time()
1530779379.18
```

Is it a problem of Win 10 OS? I believe there should be some lib cater this situation. Please help.

Comment: have you tried time.clock() ?

Comment: yes,
print time.clock()
output is always 0.0

Comment: the time_ns seems to be available only on python 3.7 but 2.7

Comment: my mistake, time.clock() should work for me. Need to try that for multiprocessing tho

Answer (score 0):

As written in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) this `datetime.datetime.now()` actually returns you microseconds:

> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.**microseconds**

So in your case `185000` is microseconds

Comment: I think mcsy meant that only the milliseconds part of that ever was non-zero.

Comment: ya anyway thanks Dilshat, I get my solution by using time.clock()